# On launching developer tool in chrome cursor changes to round black

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have a problem in chrome. Whenever I launch developer tool in chrome it changes the cursor and closing it returns to the default pointer like cursor.

I am not getting what changes caused it and how can I can revert back?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Chrome Developer Tools, in the lower right corner click on the gear icon. That will open dev tools settings screen. Uncheck `Emulate touch events` parameter there and you'll get your normal cursor back.

Update:
It seems like newer version of Chrome(at least my 33 beta) hid that option even deeper. From the developer tools show the console by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> then switch to `Emulation` tab and then `Sensors` sub-menu. From there make sure `Emulate touch events` is unchecked.

Comment: The `Emulate touch events` is no longer there. Does anyone know how to turn this off in the current version of Chrome?

Comment: @NeluMalancea see my updated instructions.

Comment: seems now it's called Touch -> Forced enabled (in the Sensors tab directly since I don't see an Emulation tab)

Comment: Yet there is no force disabled. Would be convenient.

Answer (score 4):

Open chrome developer tool
ensure that your cursor is on the developer tool page.
do ctrl+Shift+M (This is toggle device toolbar. even you can changes ur round cursor to arrow by clicking on toggle device icon present at the top left of dev tool. )

Answer (score 3):

Ctrl-Shift-M to open devices > click the top right 3 dots > Add Device type.

Then in the new drop down that appears next to No Throttling you can turn touch on and off.

[image: Click here]

Comment: 2023: CTRL-SHIFT-M, to turn on responsive.  Then: Youtube video solves it.  Easy. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pxhm9qoF-zw

Answer (score 2):

I accidentally switched on the "Emulate Touch Events" mode. After following all the answers above, I could not locate that option anymore. Hence, I did the following:

1. Open the settings of Developer Mode (by clicking on the gear icon)
2. Scroll down to the end and select "Restore defaults and reload"

this has fixed my issue.